# Totalling a column based on another column

Tags: bash, awk

Say I have a text file items.txt

```
Another Purple Item:1:3:01APR13
Another Green Item:1:8:02APR13
Another Yellow Item:1:3:01APR13
Another Orange Item:5:3:04APR13
```

Where the 2nd column is price and the 3rd is quantity. How could I loop through this in bash such that each unique date had a total of `price * quantity`?

Comment: As much as I would like to, I'm trying to do this in shell.

Comment: Just curious, but why?

Comment: @troelskn, bash is also a scripting language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this awk one-liner:

```
awk -F: '{v[$NF]+=$2*$3}END{for(x in v)print x, v[x]}' file
```

result:

```
01APR13 6
04APR13 15
02APR13 8
```

**EDIT** sorting

as I commented, there are two approaches to sort the output by date, I just take the simpler one: ^_^:

```
kent$  awk -F: '{ v[$NF]+=$2*$3}END{for(x in v){"date -d\""x"\" +%F"|getline d;print d,x,v[x]}}' file|sort|awk '$0=$2" "$3'
01APR13 6
02APR13 8
04APR13 15
```

Comment: Brilliant, is it possible to sort them by date as well?

Comment: yes, it is possible. you could either play arrays in awk, or add a temp column to the output to help sorting, then remove it. The awk way needs single process, but implementation is more complex, the later way is simpler, but needs more processes. `awk|sort|(awk/sed/cut)`

Comment: @Shannon I added an example to output sorted result (by date)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at bash's [associative arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html).

You can create a map of dates to values, then go over the lines, calculate `price*quantity` and add it to the value currently in the map or insert it if non-existent.

Comment: Are associative arrays available in version 3.2 of bash?

Comment: @Shannon, no it's new in bash 4 I think.